# ¿Cómo modificar los datos de una columna de mi data.frame de excel para que las "," aparezcan como puntos sólo para algunas variables?

Tags: r

Tengo un fichero de datos que contiene 3 variables en las que los decimales se expresan con comas, mientras que el resto está expresado con puntos.

Leyendo el fichero con la orden que ya conocía para los .txt :

`datos=read_excel("Coca Cola Sur.xlsx", dec=",")`

Obtengo un error.
¿Cómo podría solucionarlo entonces?

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Que error obtienes? El separador decimal, actúa sobre todas las columnas numéricas, no puedes configurarlo solo para algunas variables.

Answer (score 0):

Voy a crear un ejemplo en donde dos columnas de las tres tienen los decimales con coma y no con punto.

```
df<-data.frame(var1=c("123,35","345,34", "134,56","158,89"),
               var2=c(132.34,678.5,456.77,333.45),
               var3=c("101,54","222,56","456,78","546,67"))

    var1   var2   var3
  123,35 132.34 101,54
  345,34 678.50 222,56
  134,56 456.77 456,78
  158,89 333.45 546,67
```

Como se ve, en la columna 1 y 3 el símbolo para separar decimales son las comas. Entonces puedo cambiarlas de la siguiente manera.

```
df[,c(1,3)]<-apply(df[,c(1,3)], 2, function(x){
  gsub(",",".",x)
})
```

A lo que nos queda ya sin las comas decimales.

```
    var1   var2   var3
  123.35 132.34 101.54
  345.34 678.50 222.56
  134.56 456.77 456.78
  158.89 333.45 546.67
```